# NHaml T4 templates for CRUD?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, t4, nhaml

I want to ask if anyone has or has seen T4 templates for NHaml that are the same as the default T4 CRUD (List, Create etc) templates from MVC 2.0?

Comment: ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/te/NorthAmerica/2010/pptx/WEB206.pptx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very good introduction for Asp.net mvc 3,Nhaml,T4
http://www.b-fil.com/blog/2010/10/17/aspnet-mvc3-ef-code-first-razor-sample-project/

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have seen has this link but not for mvc:

[Can NHaml be used as a general purpose template engine? (outside of MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384022/can-nhaml-be-used-as-a-general-purpose-template-engine-outside-of-mvc)

There doesn't seem to be standard NHaml T4 templates for data access.

Answer (score -4):

I have not but I am sure you could easily write them.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: Wow two down votes. Guess people just want everything handed to them instead of doing it themselves :)